# TeamCity's build agent unable to find PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, teamcity

I have TC's build agent installed on Windows 2008 R2 SP1 Core. The server has PowerShell 2.0 installed (double checked, and actually from PS downloaded the TC installation). Looking at some build configuration I see these being incompatible with this agent, because `powershell_x86`/`powershell_x64` is required. I tried deleting build agents dirs to force upgrade, but no luck. Interestingly if I provide `powershell_x86`, `powershell_x86_Path` (and for 64bit) variables into config file manually, everything runs fine.

Is there anything I can do to have the build agent find PowerShell automatically? What/where is it looking for it? Maybe the 'Core' is problem.

Comment: It would work if you add same variables in buildAgent.properties file

Comment: That's what I did (it's in text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that it needs both `MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell` (x64) and `MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell-WOW64` (x86) (and dependencies), else it's not able to find it. Probably some registry mapping bitness magic in Windows.

Comment: please elaborate. I's not clear for me how to fix detection. BTW, we access patches.

Comment: I don't know either. Probably the process should run in 64bit, if it's detecting 64bit PowerShell (only).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the some of the source for the PowerShell plugin at http://svn.jetbrains.org/teamcity/plugins/powershell/trunk/powershell-agent/src/main/java/jetbrains/buildServer/powershell/agent/detect/PowerShellRegistry.java it mentions this page on PowerShell detection logic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/06/25/detection-logic-poweshell-installation.aspx. Have a look at that page, it talks about checking the registry. Maybe you're missing some registry keys.